# Is Google aware of multiple user profiles sharing the same Android device?

Tags: privacy, google-pixel, profiles

If I create two user profiles* on my Google Pixel device, is Google (potentially) aware that both of them share the same device--as per privacy policy and/or actual implementation?

If so, is there any way to prevent Google from knowing which user profiles (identified as Android accounts) share a device, except switching to a custom ROM?

[*] As managed in `Settings > System > Multiple Users` as of Android 11; not to be confused with `Settings > Accounts`.

Comment: I don't think Google will be aware unless you sign in to Google in each profile.

Answer (score 0):

If your Internet provider uses IPv6 and your device is using IPv6, and you use any service or web site that uses Google resources/services in any way Google can identify your device by it's IP address if you switch the profiles without rebooting no matter what ROM you have installed.

As modern devices with Google PlayServices + PlayStore installed contact PlayStore for updates even if no Google account has been set-up on one of your profiles.

Comment: Could you share some links showing that both IDs are constant across user profiles (Settings > System > Multiple Users as per Android 11) and/or Google's servers are involved in issuing them? My research so far: ((A)): [ANDROID_ID is different per user on the phone; no mention of servers involved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43393373), as of Android O; ((B)): GSF ID [seems to be local for user profile](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.mobile.android/c/TWiqCS-r2vY/m/Q76sDBMcDAAJ); [GSF(ID?)-free setup seems feasible](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.mobile.android/c/TWiqCS-r2vY/m/p0udAsUHCgAJ).

Comment: @wassrubleff In your original question you talked about profile (-> Google accounts), not user profiles.

Comment: I referred to Profiles (as opposed to Accounts) as widely used by Google, [eg here](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/multi-user).

Comment: If you are only talking about user profiles I have adapted my answer.

Comment: So if two user profiles with different accounts signed in to Google Play, how specifically does Google know that they share the same device rather than run on different devices?

Comment: See my answer. The IPv6 address if used is device-wide (hence also independent of the used profile) and IPv6 is not changed by NAT, hence Google usually sees the interface identifier part of the IPv6 address which is enough to identify your device in the current Wifi when your device contacts any Google server.

Comment: Assuming that cross-matching by IPv6 can be circumvented by distinct VPNs and blocking non-VPN network usage, is there other way for Google to find out that two profiles share the same device?